# Mysql Distinct max column while joining two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables I'm trying to join and get a unique value in one column based on the max value of another column plus an identifier in another table. This is my structure.

```
Partial Table 1 (reward_webuid):
╔════╦═════════╦═════════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ ID ║ WEB_UID ║ ITEM_ID ║ PLAYERID ║      TIMESTAMP      ║ EXPIRED ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════╣
║  8 ║ 1209520 ║   73410 ║  1926406 ║ 2013-01-05 04:47:06 ║       0 ║
║  9 ║ 1209520 ║   73425 ║  1926406 ║ 2013-01-02 09:40:27 ║       1 ║
║ 10 ║ 1209520 ║   73424 ║  1926406 ║ 2013-01-05 09:40:05 ║       0 ║
║ 11 ║ 1209520 ║   73425 ║  1926406 ║ 2013-01-05 09:40:27 ║       0 ║
║ 12 ║ 1209521 ║   73424 ║ 21555896 ║ 2013-01-05 01:33:20 ║       0 ║
║ 13 ║ 1209521 ║   75000 ║  5599854 ║ 2013-01-05 01:35:09 ║       1 ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════╝

Partial Table 2 (rewards):
╔═════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║ ITEM_ID ║ CUST_LOADOUT_ID ║ REWARD_LEVEL ║ EXPIRY_TIME ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║   73410 ║               1 ║            5 ║           0 ║
║   73424 ║               2 ║           10 ║           0 ║
║   73425 ║               3 ║           15 ║          30 ║
║   75000 ║               4 ║           50 ║          60 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Sample return of what I would like to get (cust_loadout_id and playerID for the maximum value of reward level based on item_id in table 1 that hasn't expired yet) there should only be one value per playerID

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╗
║ PLAYERID ║ CUST_LOADOUT_ID ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1926406 ║               3 ║
║ 21555896 ║               2 ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Would be grateful if anyone could help with this. I searched and most queries related to the same table or 3 or more tables. The best I've managed is to return data I needed but it wasn't ordered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    reward_webuid a
        INNER JOIN rewards b
            ON a.item_id = b.item_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  aa.PLAYERID, MAX(bb.REWARD_LEVEL) maxLevel
            FROM    reward_webuid aa
                    INNER JOIN rewards bb
                        ON aa.item_id = bb.item_ID
            WHERE   aa.expired = 0
            GROUP   BY aa.PLAYERID
        ) c ON  a.PLAYERID = c.PLAYERID AND
                b.REWARD_LEVEL = c.maxLevel AND
                a.Expired = 0
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/029f6/9)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*selected columns only*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/029f6/10)

Comment: Thanks JW - I had to throw a DISTINCT on your selected columns demo but it worked perfectly.